# Pausing a SpriteKit Game - UIApplicationWillResignActive vs. UIApplicationDidBecomeActive?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I understand the differences between the two methods but I was wondering if there were disadvantages to using UIApplicationWillResignActive as opposed to UIApplicationDidBecomeActive (or, UIApplicationDidEnterBackground) when doing something such as pause a SpriteKit game. I've been roaming past threads on the site and have noticed that generally in response to questions asking how to pause a SpriteKit game, UIApplicationDidBecomeActive and UIApplicationDidEnterBackground are suggested as opposed to UIApplicationWillResignActive. Since UIApplicationWillResignActive also pauses the games in response to Siri/Calls, wouldn't this be the better method to use when dealing with pausing SpriteKit games and such or is there some disadvantage to using it?

Below I have my Notifications and pause function:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.pauseGame), name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

//OR

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.pauseGame), name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
```

Pause function:

```
func pauseGame(){
    print(self.scene?.isPaused)
    if sceneIsPaused == true || isGameOver == true{
        return
    }

    leftMobGenTimer.invalidate()
    rightMobGenTimer.invalidate()
    genDragonTimer.invalidate()
    checkNinjaTimer.invalidate()

    chiStrikeTimer.invalidate()
    randCoinTimer.invalidate()

    print("Timer stopped?")

    if soundEnabled == true{
     player.pause()
    }

    self.scene?.isPaused = true
    sceneIsPaused = true
    makePauseView()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pausing**

This is from the docs about [applicationWillResignActive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive) method:

> You should use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and
>   throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to
>   pause the game. An app in the inactive state should do minimal work
>   while it waits to transition to either the active or background state.

So this method is meant to be used when it comes to pausing the games.

**Unpausing**

iirc, game should be automatically unpaused when app transition from inactive to active state. This is the moment when `applicationDidBecomeActive` method is called, so in some cases you may want to pause the game here as well... But that depends on your game.

I don't know why did you mention combination of `applicationDidBecomeActive` & `applicationDidEnterBackground` for pausing/unpausing... Because it is probably too late to pause the game in `applicationDidEnterBackground` and technically it is not needed to unpause the game in `applicationDidBecomeActive` because this is done automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation! Definitely cleared it up for me and the `applicationDidEnterBackground` delay explanation actually helped me solve another issue I was dealing with in another app. Thanks again!